# Combine two divs together in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-animate

I have an application that I have written in jQuery that I am currently re-writing in AngularJS. I have a situation where two twin beds (div/css based) can be combined into a king bed and vise versa via a bootstrap button toggle.

To make this post more generically useful to other viewers, let's just think of this situation as separating and combining two rounded border divs. So, we have two rectangle divs with rounded borders and margins between them. There is an arbitrary amount of these divs, meaning there could be 2, there could be 7, but only one pair should combine together (in the case of 7, 3 individual pairs can combine and separate with their paired div, and one is left out).

The following comment code snippet has some ng-class information for the combining css:

```
<!-- <div data-ng-class="{'bed combinableAttachedBed':bed.bedType='Twin-Combinable'}" ng-class-odd="'leftBed'" ng-class-even="'rightBed'" > </div> -->
```

Here is a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4JO0v8thqABkH4gy7di0?p=preview

What is the cleanest angular way to handle such a situation?

---

Note: I am already using ng-animate, so any solution using that is welcome. I also welcome directive based solutions. I basically am looking for the best practice way to handle this situation. I have tried angular html only ng-class based solutions, but that just doesn't seem like the best way to handle this situation.

Comment: provide code, plunker

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the best solution would involve `ng-class` and some CSS. You could easily remove the border and margin from the closer side of the combined 'beds' with CSS and that way your angular code wont get complicated by how things are displayed.

Comment: This is the approach I have been attempting at, but since I'm already using ng-class for several other things, I was thinking I would take another approach. I'm taking another stab at this approach now.